# How to disable font anti-aliasing (aka font smoothing) for the text inside any NSView?

Tags: swift, fonts, macos-mojave

We're developing a Mac App which supports Mac OS 10.11 or higher. However, we are facing [this font anti-aliasing issue](http://osxdaily.com/2018/09/26/fix-blurry-thin-fonts-text-macos-mojave/) for users running Mac OS 10.14. This happens only in some text views and buttons in our app. The text in those views looks blurry in the app, while other texts are just fine.

Is there any way to stop font smoothing (aka stop font anti-aliasing) for the texts in the only the views we want to? Apple documentation was not of much help.